# How to align a container to the left and extend it to the right edge of the screen?

Tags: html, css, styling, web-frontend, webflow

I'm trying to align a container to the left side of the screen with the rest of the Sites Content and have it extend all the way to the right edge of the screen. I want it to be responsive and work on different screen sizes. In my case, the container contains an image gallery and I want it to be aligned with other containers on the page.

[This is a screenshot of the Screendesign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aU9D.jpg)

I've tried using flexbox and setting the container to 100% width, but that doesn't work because it makes the container extend beyond the right edge of the screen. I don't want to use absolute positioning because it will break the layout on different screen sizes.

I'm using Webflow to build my website, so any solutions specific to Webflow would be appreciated. Thank you! But also CSS Solutions are Welcome

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.